# How to readline in python while ignoring spaces and new lines. Python

Tags: python, file

I am trying to read from a file and append it to an array in python.
But while I use:

```
while True:
    repos.append(fileRepos.readline())
    print(repos[counter])
    counter+=1
    if counter > 5274:
        break
```

The thing is that my file "fileRepos" has 5274 lines. Every line should contain a name of a repository. But when I print out the `repos` array some objects are empty. My guess is that it reads some spaces and some lines as objects. But shouldn't it be able to read the whole line as the txt file is? How can I solve this?

The file looks like this:

**repos.txt:**

```
aco-palinda-1
aco-palinda-2
aco-palinda-3
aco-quicksort
aco-week-1
acol-week-10
aco-week-11
aco-week-12
aco-week-13
```

Comment: Post a sample of the file.

Comment: @AdamGold Sec bro

Comment: It only looks that way. Your list `repos` still only contains 5274 lines.

Comment: One quick solution might be to change your second line to: `repos.append(fileRepos.readline().strip())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
repos = []
with open(filename) as infile:          #Open file for read
    for line in infile:                 #Iterate Each line
        line = line.strip()             #Strip leading and trailing space
        if line:                        #Check if line is empty
            repos.append(line)          #Append repo name to list.
```